# How to check if a value is already assigned to a key and vice versa in a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to make a dict in python to assign each letter (from A to Z) with an other (or himself) randomly.
For exemple *A:S B:C C:B D:D ... S:A ... Y:Z Z:Y*.

My code is:

```
import random
tblconex = {}
alphabet = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C", 4: "D", 5: "E", 6: "F", 7: "G", 8: "H", 9: "I", 10: "J", 11: "K", 12: "L", 13: "M", 14: "N", 15: "O", 16: "P", 17: "Q", 18: "R", 19: "S", 20: "T", 21: "U", 22: "V", 23: "W", 24: "X", 25: "Y", 26: "Z"}
while n < 27:
    var = alphabet[random.randint(1, 26)] #We randomly choose a letter
    if var in tblconex or alphabet[n] in tblconex: #We test if she is not already assign to an other
        n += 1
    else:
        tblconex.update({alphabet[n]: var}) #We assign it
        tblconex.update({var: alphabet[n]}) 
    n += 1
z=1
while z<len(tblconex)+1: #We print our letters
    print("    ", alphabet[z], " : ", tblconex[alphabet[z]])
    z += 1
```

But when I launch it he stop after few letter with a Key error because he don't assign all letters and I don't understand why.

Sorry for my bad english i'm French ;)

Thanks!

Comment: `n` is initilaized with `0` (not part of the code)?

Comment: You can use `random.choice()` with each letter of the alphabet and remove the item picked each time

Comment: yes i missed this : n=1

Comment: I think you need a more tab in the second n += 1, you are incrementing n twice when is already sattisfied the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you increment `n`, even if you already added the element to the dictionary. So if you already added the element, it still *counts* as one. In case it was *not* added yet, it counts as two, but there are thus cases possible where

Anyway, there is no reason to do this, we can first make a random string by shuffling the characters, and then "stitching" these together, like:

The fundamental problem is that you increment `n`, even if you already added the element to the dictionary. So if you already added the element, it still *counts* as one. In case it was *not* added yet, it counts as two, but there are thus cases possible where

Anyway, there is no reason to do this, we can first make a random string by shuffling the characters, and then "stitching" these together, like:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from random import shuffle

dt = list(ascii_uppercase)
shuffle(dt)
dt = iter(dt)

result = {k: v for a, b in zip(dt, dt) for k, v in ((a,b), (b, a))}
```

Or in case a character can "pair" together with itself, we can implement it like:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from random import shuffle, randint

dt = list(ascii_uppercase)
shuffle(dt)

result = {}
i = 0
while i < len(dt):
    d = randint(0,len(dt)-i-1 > 0)
    k = dt[i]
    v = dt[i+d]
    result.update({k: v, v: k})
    i += 1 + d

assert len(result) == len(ascii_uppercase)
assert len(set(result.values())) == len(ascii_uppercase)
```

Both algorithms work in linear time, since they make a single pass over a list of random characters, and each time link the previous with the next character (or the current character with itself).

Comment: Wait, when I test your second code it say: NameError: name 'string_uppercase' is not defined

Comment: Err.... brain burp... I meant `result.update({k:v, v:k})` - sorry ... else you'll get *interesting* results :)

Comment: You need to import it, with the import statement above.

Comment: I already tried but he said me:ImportError: cannot import name 'string_uppercase' when the code is:     from string import ascii_uppercase
    from string import string_uppercase
    from random import shuffle
    
    result = {}
    for k in string_uppercase:
        if k not in result:
            v = choice(string_uppercase)
            result.update({k:v, v:k})

Comment: @apprentice_coder: it is `ascii_uppercase`. I fixed it, there were some mistakes in the second approach. My appologies.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `random.choice` to select from the alphabet and remove 1 letter each time:

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_uppercase
values = dict.fromkeys(letters)
for letter in values:
    choose = random.choice(letters)
    if choose in values.values():
        continue
        # see note **
    letters.remove(choose)
    values[letter] = choose

for k, v in values.items():
    values[v] = k
```

** this checks if the choice has already been assigned, if so, skip the key and continue. This will ensure A maps to B and B maps to A. At the end I add the skipped pairs back in but with the key/value swapped

Comment: `{letter: None for letter in letters}` can be written as `dict.fromkeys(letters)`...

Comment: Typo in last line: `chose` should be `choose`